# Share common functionality between two static classes

Tags: c#, static, static-classes

I need to share some common functionality between two static classes:

```
public static class Class
{
    public static void ClassMethod()
    {
       SharedMethod<object>();
    }


    //ideally a private method
    internal static void SharedMethod<T>()
    {

    }
}

public static class GenericClass<T>
{
    public static void GenericClassMethod()
    {
       SharedMethod<T>();
    }
}
```

Is there a better design here? `internal` is my last choice, but really the method `SharedMethod` has no significance outside those two classes.

Requirements:

1. I can't combine them to a single class, I need them separately, one generic and other not.
2. The classes need not be strictly static, but they shouldn't be instantiable or inheritable.
3. `SharedMethod` can fall in either class, it doesn't matter.

Comment: what is the technical reason that they can't be combined? in particular, I'm thinking a single static class with a combination of generic and non-generic methods, for exmaple

Comment: @MarcGravell its more semantic reasons. `Class` and `GenericClass<>` are related and they serve similar purposes, but the idea is conveyed better by having them separate. Its more like `Tuple` and `Tuple<>` etc.

Comment: @nawfal Usually I like abstract software architecture questions, but I think noone can help you without further specifying what your classes represent, what operations they have (and what is shared), and how they are supposed to be used in an application. The `Tuple` and `Tuple<>` example is too trivial, because one can simply define `public class Tuple : Tuple<object>` (since it's not static). C# doesn't have `friends`, so `internal` (be it an internal class or an internal method) is probably your best bet.

Comment: can't you use the Singleton pattern? Of course the classes wouldn't be static anymore, but you'll only have one instance of each. Also, in your code, did you meant `Class.SharedMethod<T>();` ?

Comment: @dialer `public class Tuple : Tuple<object>` is not an option because that means the `Tuple<>` class is inheritable which I would like to avoid. But you're right I should have been more specific with the use case. In the end I went with Marc's way of combining the classes. I will add the solution I ended up with as an answer

Comment: @ppetrov I can have a singleton but how is it helping me in protecting the visibility of the shared function to just those two classes? Ya it doest mean `Class.SharedMethod<T>()`

Comment: @nawfal posted it in my answer, your shared method is protected that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This workaround doesn't meet all 3 requirements (which is impossible imo) but it made up for the same functionality I wanted.

I ended up using a single class as Marc suggested in comments. But then I had the generic class nested inside the non generic class to act for the generic functionality.

```
public static class Class
{
    public static void ClassMethod()
    {
        SharedMethod<object>();
    }



    static void SharedMethod<T>()
    {
        //----
    }



    public static void GenericClassMethod<T>()
    {
        return GenericClass<T>.SharedMethod();
    }

    static class GenericClass<T> 
    {
        static void SharedMethod()
        {
            //available here since private members of outer class is visible to nested class
            SharedMethod<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

So now, even though the calling has to be done little differently from how I wanted it originally in the question, functionally both are equal.

Answer (score 1):

First I thought you can't meet the 3 rules, but then I thought about reflection, and I came up with something that works, but **that shouldn't be used unless you really don't have any other way of accomplishing what you need**

**I don't recommend using it** but just for fun I'll post the code:

```
public static class ClassA
{
    private static void sharedMethod<T>() { }

    public static void ClassMethod()
    {
        sharedMethod<object>();
    }
}

public static class GenericClass<T>
{
    static MethodInfo sharedMethodInfo;

    static GenericClass()
    {
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(ClassA).GetMethod("sharedMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        sharedMethodInfo = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(T) });
    }

    public static void GenericClassMethod()
    {
        sharedMethodInfo.Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare the classes as sealed - that way they won't be inheritable.

If you change the permission from private to protected that way anything in your application can see the method but will be invisible to another application trying to use your methods.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Doesn't help, since the shared functionality still has to be `public/internal`

Comment: That's just wrong. Your compiler will probably scream at you for having protected members in a sealed class. That doesn't make sense. Maybe you mixed up words and meant to say something else?

Answer (score -1):

If you can use the singleton pattern, you can have 2 classes, with the generic class inheriting from the standard one. Also you can keep your static methods, here is what it can look like:

```
internal class ClassA
{
    private static ClassA _instance;
    private static ClassA Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null) _instance = new ClassA();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    protected void sharedMethod<T>() { }

    public static void ClassMethod()
    {
        Instance.sharedMethod<object>();
    }
}

public sealed class GenericClass<T> : ClassA
{
    private static GenericClass<T> _instance;
    private static GenericClass<T> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null) _instance = new GenericClass<T>();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public static void GenericClassMethod()
    {
        Instance.sharedMethod<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: what this means is `ClassA` is inheritable, violates rule 2

Comment: yep forgot about that... But if you want only 2 classes sharing one method there is only two ways of doing this: having a third one that contains the method, but then the method would be exposed, or inherit from one class... BTW you can make ClassA internal, it would be still less accesible, and I find it safer than the internal method option

Comment: In that case my first approach in the question was simpler. Btw, you can make your generic class sealed

Comment: yep also true I'll edit that, and yes it was simpler, but it exposed your shared method, which you didn't want if I understood you correctly

Comment: yes thats right, this is another layer of protection though not fully protecting :)

Comment: Not fully, but I don't think there's a fully protecting way of doing this if you want public methods on both of your separated classes, so here it's about choosing the most protecting solution, or going with one class implementation (or nested class implementation as you did, but here you only have one class exposed, it depends on what you need to be exposed)

Comment: @nawfal Actually after some sleep and thinking, there is an implementation that doesn't break any of the 3 rules, but it's ugly (you'd have to use reflection), anyway I'll post it in another answer just for fun

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't think of it, go for it. But to tell you its not at all something someone would recommend :)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it either :) (and I'll say it in the answer)